# How can I override a method in a wcf service contract to allow for different web methods?

Tags: wcf, backbone.js

I am using a wcf web service as the persistence layer for a backbone.js application.

```
  [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    public IEnumerable<AnalysisParameterSet> AnalysisParameters()
    {
     // implementation
    }

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
    public void AnalysisParameters(IEnumerable<AnalysisParameterSet> parameterSets)
    {
     // implementation
    }
```

I would like to create two methods on the service with the same name, but different signatures, one for GET and one for POST.

However wcf is complaining that there are 2 methods with the same name. I am aware I could use the name property of the OperationContract to differentiate them. This is not ideal as backbone prefers for the methods to share the same name.

Can i use the same method name for both GET and POST?

If I can't do this in WCF. How would I modifiy backbone.js to use a different method for post and Get.

Comment: WCF does **NOT** support overloading of methods that differ just by their signature. You will have to create two distinct methods with distinct names.

Comment: "*This is not ideal as backbone prefers for the methods to share the same name.*" Could you elaborate? As I have no knowledge of WCF, how are your server call routed? (How does the server know what function/method to execute?)

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you want is something like:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/AnalysisParameters")]
public IEnumerable<AnalysisParameterSet> GetAnalysisParameters()
{
 // implementation
}

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/AnalysisParameters")]
public void PostAnalysisParameters(IEnumerable<AnalysisParameterSet> parameterSets)
{
 // implementation
}
```

Depending on the http method (post/get), one or the other function will be called.